# Silent symbol collision?

Tags: c, gcc, static, linker

Posted on the Raspberry Stackexchange before, closed as off-topic, so here I am.

The following program compiles cleanly with `gcc main.c -lpigpio -lpthread -Wall -Wextra`. I'm using gcc 8.3.0 (crosscompiler or normal compiler doesn't change anything).

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pigpio.h>

void listen() {
        printf("hi from listen\n");
}

int main() {
        gpioInitialise();
        printf("hi from main\n");
        gpioTerminate();
        return 0;
}
```

No warnings, yet the program happily prints

```
hi from listen
hi from main
```

The cause seems to be that `gpioInitialise()` tries to call listen(2) from `<sys/sockets.h>` [here](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/blob/master/pigpio.c#L7209), but instead calls the function from `main.c`. Of course, this doesn't work and results in an error message from the pigpio library:

```
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx pthSocketThread: setsockopt() fail, closing socket -1
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx pthSocketThread: accept failed (Bad file descriptor)
```

Question: How come that gcc links a function with a completly different signature without throwing any errors? I know about `static`, but I want to make sense of this to learn from it. Surely it can't be as simple as listen(2) not being declared as static?

Comment: Unlike C++, there are no function prototype signature information in an external C library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linker allows you to interpose symbols like this for debugging, profiling, etc. purposes. Unfortunately at link stage the typing information is generally not available so linker can not perform any sanity checking to verify that expected and actual signatures match. One might argue that with `-g` this would be possible but noone cared enough to implement this (this might be a good home project though).

`Static` would help in your case because it would prevent `listen` from being exported and libc's `listen` from being overridden.

As a side note, on ELF systems (Linux) situation is ever worse because they allow runtime symbol interposition (i.e. libraries compete for who wins over symbol names at program startup). This is typically resolved with `static` or `-fvisiblity=hidden` (unfortunately many libraries [do not use them](https://github.com/yugr/ShlibVisibilityChecker)).